# WPF MenuItem Color when set to black wont change to grey when disabled

Tags: wpf

When the top menu item foreground is set to black and the background is set to white everything works fine for both XP and Windows 7.  But we are using a main menu bar that is black and with white foreground.  This causes issues in windows 7 only.  Why is it that when you set a menuitem foreground to black it wont change to grey when disabled.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem with Windows XP and 7.

The Foreground="Black" attribute overrides the built in style trigger that is a function of IsEnabled.

To accomplish what you are looking for requires building your own style with a Trigger on IsEnabled.  The following code shows how to do this in-line, although you're likely to want to pull the Style into a resources section and use it on all of your menu items.

```
<MenuItem Header="My Item" IsEnabled="{Binding MyItemEnabled}">
    <MenuItem.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.Style>
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: By the way, instead of having the Trigger set the Foreground property to Gray, a better approach is to set the Opacity property to 50.

Comment: I don't know if this is just a difference in versions, but `Opacity` is a double; it should be set to 1.0 for enabled and 0.5 for disabled.